# Error Connecting to Snowflake after switching to Key-Pair authentication

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have multiple pipelines running on Airflow and these pipelines dump data to Snowflake.

When I used basic authentication(username and password), I didn't get any error. However, when I switched to using Key-Pair authentication, the pipelines failed

```
WARNING - Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fee180c32b0>, 'Connection to 1 timed out. (connect timeout=60)')': /%5Cxf0%60%5Cx9bO4%5D%5Cn~%5Cxdfw%5Cxf4%5Cr%5B%5Cx9a%5Cx00%5Cx1eok?%5Cxbf2%5Cxd3%7DZ%5Cx02%5Cx9fg%5Cx13R%5Cxe1%25%5Cxda%5Cx99%5Cxa5R%5Cxa0%5Cxf0%5Cr%5Cxe7K%5Cx1b?-%5Cxe5$6%5Cxa3%5CxccGBv%5Cxa4%5Cxa1n%5Cx0e%5Cx82P%5Cxa9%5Cx07$%5Cx1bh%5Cx11%5Cxac%5Cx03%5Cx80i%5Cx9b%5Cxbe%5Cx8d%5Cxc5%5Cxbd%5CxddD%5Cx8c%5Cx14%5Cxca%5Cxb6%5Cx9b%3C%5Cxb6%5Cxe6%5Cxb8%5Cx9e%5Cx9e.%5Cxa2y(%5Cxb2%5Cxb8%60%5Cx11%5Cx01%5Cxc8Z%5Cx04U9%5Cx84%5Cxe3%5Cxf0%5Cxe0%5Cxca%5Cx9b%5Cxacv%5Cxd5EB%5Cx13U%5C'%5Cx13M'&warehouse=LOAD_WH.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=d3096edc-10f9-49ee-b8cb-79566f11b012
[2024-02-20 12:34:33,528] {network.py:940} ERROR - HTTPSConnectionPool(host='1', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /%5Cxf0%60%5Cx9bO4%5D%5Cn~%5Cxdfw%5Cxf4%5Cr%5B%5Cx9a%5Cx00%5Cx1eok?%5Cxbf2%5Cxd3%7DZ%5Cx02%5Cx9fg%5Cx13R%5Cxe1%25%5Cxda%5Cx99%5Cxa5R%5Cxa0%5Cxf0%5Cr%5Cxe7K%5Cx1b?-%5Cxe5$6%5Cxa3%5CxccGBv%5Cxa4%5Cxa1n%5Cx0e%5Cx82P%5Cxa9%5Cx07$%5Cx1bh%5Cx11%5Cxac%5Cx03%5Cx80i%5Cx9b%5Cxbe%5Cx8d%5Cxc5%5Cxbd%5CxddD%5Cx8c%5Cx14%5Cxca%5Cxb6%5Cx9b%3C%5Cxb6%5Cxe6%5Cxb8%5Cx9e%5Cx9e.%5Cxa2y(%5Cxb2%5Cxb8%60%5Cx11%5Cx01%5Cxc8Z%5Cx04U9%5Cx84%5Cxe3%5Cxf0%5Cxe0%5Cxca%5Cx9b%5Cxacv%5Cxd5EB%5Cx13U%5C'%5Cx13M'&warehouse=LOAD_WH.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=d3096edc-10f9-49ee-b8cb-79566f11b012 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fee18385550>, 'Connection to 1 timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/test/snowflake_test.py", line 120, in write_from_gcs
    if not conn:
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/pandas_tools.py", line 164, in write_pandas
    cursor = conn.cursor()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 650, in cursor
    Error.errorhandler_wrapper(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 275, in errorhandler_wrapper
    handed_over = Error.hand_to_other_handler(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 333, in hand_to_other_handler
    connection.errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 209, in default_errorhandler
    raise error_class(
snowflake.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 250002 (08003): None: Connection is closed


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/urllib3/connection.py", line 358, in connect
    self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/urllib3/connection.py", line 179, in _new_conn
    raise ConnectTimeoutError(
snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fee18385550>, 'Connection to 1 timed out. (connect timeout=60)')


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 815, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='1', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /%5Cxf0%60%5Cx9bO4%5D%5Cn~%5Cxdfw%5Cxf4%5Cr%5B%5Cx9a%5Cx00%5Cx1eok?%5Cxbf2%5Cxd3%7DZ%5Cx02%5Cx9fg%5Cx13R%5Cxe1%25%5Cxda%5Cx99%5Cxa5R%5Cxa0%5Cxf0%5Cr%5Cxe7K%5Cx1b?-%5Cxe5$6%5Cxa3%5CxccGBv%5Cxa4%5Cxa1n%5Cx0e%5Cx82P%5Cxa9%5Cx07$%5Cx1bh%5Cx11%5Cxac%5Cx03%5Cx80i%5Cx9b%5Cxbe%5Cx8d%5Cxc5%5Cxbd%5CxddD%5Cx8c%5Cx14%5Cxca%5Cxb6%5Cx9b%3C%5Cxb6%5Cxe6%5Cxb8%5Cx9e%5Cx9e.%5Cxa2y(%5Cxb2%5Cxb8%60%5Cx11%5Cx01%5Cxc8Z%5Cx04U9%5Cx84%5Cxe3%5Cxf0%5Cxe0%5Cxca%5Cx9b%5Cxacv%5Cxd5EB%5Cx13U%5C'%5Cx13M'&warehouse=LOAD_WH.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=d3096edc-10f9-49ee-b8cb-79566f11b012 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fee18385550>, 'Connection to 1 timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 1026, in _request_exec
    raw_ret = session.request(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 553, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
snowflake.connector.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='1', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /%5Cxf0%60%5Cx9bO4%5D%5Cn~%5Cxdfw%5Cxf4%5Cr%5B%5Cx9a%5Cx00%5Cx1eok?%5Cxbf2%5Cxd3%7DZ%5Cx02%5Cx9fg%5Cx13R%5Cxe1%25%5Cxda%5Cx99%5Cxa5R%5Cxa0%5Cxf0%5Cr%5Cxe7K%5Cx1b?-%5Cxe5$6%5Cxa3%5CxccGBv%5Cxa4%5Cxa1n%5Cx0e%5Cx82P%5Cxa9%5Cx07$%5Cx1bh%5Cx11%5Cxac%5Cx03%5Cx80i%5Cx9b%5Cxbe%5Cx8d%5Cxc5%5Cxbd%5CxddD%5Cx8c%5Cx14%5Cxca%5Cxb6%5Cx9b%3C%5Cxb6%5Cxe6%5Cxb8%5Cx9e%5Cx9e.%5Cxa2y(%5Cxb2%5Cxb8%60%5Cx11%5Cx01%5Cxc8Z%5Cx04U9%5Cx84%5Cxe3%5Cxf0%5Cxe0%5Cxca%5Cx9b%5Cxacv%5Cxd5EB%5Cx13U%5C'%5Cx13M'&warehouse=LOAD_WH.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=d3096edc-10f9-49ee-b8cb-79566f11b012 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fee18385550>, 'Connection to 1 timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 845, in _request_exec_wrapper
    return_object = self._request_exec(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 1113, in _request_exec
    raise RetryRequest(err)
snowflake.connector.network.RetryRequest: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='1', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /%5Cxf0%60%5Cx9bO4%5D%5Cn~%5Cxdfw%5Cxf4%5Cr%5B%5Cx9a%5Cx00%5Cx1eok?%5Cxbf2%5Cxd3%7DZ%5Cx02%5Cx9fg%5Cx13R%5Cxe1%25%5Cxda%5Cx99%5Cxa5R%5Cxa0%5Cxf0%5Cr%5Cxe7K%5Cx1b?-%5Cxe5$6%5Cxa3%5CxccGBv%5Cxa4%5Cxa1n%5Cx0e%5Cx82P%5Cxa9%5Cx07$%5Cx1bh%5Cx11%5Cxac%5Cx03%5Cx80i%5Cx9b%5Cxbe%5Cx8d%5Cxc5%5Cxbd%5CxddD%5Cx8c%5Cx14%5Cxca%5Cxb6%5Cx9b%3C%5Cxb6%5Cxe6%5Cxb8%5Cx9e%5Cx9e.%5Cxa2y(%5Cxb2%5Cxb8%60%5Cx11%5Cx01%5Cxc8Z%5Cx04U9%5Cx84%5Cxe3%5Cxf0%5Cxe0%5Cxca%5Cx9b%5Cxacv%5Cxd5EB%5Cx13U%5C'%5Cx13M'&warehouse=LOAD_WH.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=d3096edc-10f9-49ee-b8cb-79566f11b012 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fee18385550>, 'Connection to 1 timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))
```

write_from_gcs function does the following activities:

- Read a file from a GCS bucket
- Get a Snowflake connection (create a new connection, if a connection does not already exist)
- Write to Snowflake

Earlier, I thought this was due to some timeout issue, so explicitly set socket_timeout while creating a snowflake connection, still got the same error.

I reverted to using username and password to authenticate to Snowflake, and the code works as expected.

It is clear, that the issue is because of changing the auth method, not sure though where exactly to check

**Basic Auth**

```
import snowflake.connector as snow
snow.connect(
    username='abc',
    password='xyz',
    account='123',
    warehouse='test',
    database='test_db',
    schema='schema',
)
```

**Key-Pair**

```
import snowflake.connector as snow
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

def get_private_key(private_key, passphrase):
    
    p_key= serialization.load_pem_private_key(
    private_key,
    password=passphrase,
    backend=default_backend()
    )

    pkb = p_key.private_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.DER,
        format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
        encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption())
    
    return pkb
    
snow.connect(
    username='abc',
    private_key=get_private_key(pkb, passphrase)
    account='123',
    warehouse='test',
    database='test_db',
    schema='schema',
)
```

Comment: may want to post that stack trace as some may not be able to access that image.

Comment: what changes did you make to connection.create_connection()?